# Crew try to make contact with an intelligent storm

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I'm trying to find a movie I saw in the late 1990s in Russian language, but it was definitely originally in English.

The plot of this movie is very like *Solaris*, but it is not the one released in 2002 and not one of the Russian movies. It takes place somewhere on the planet (not on the ship), where the whole time a storm is going on. It could be Saturn, Titan, or other.

At the top of this base is an observatory, where the crew is trying to make contact with the storm because of strange patterns in its behavior, but without success. There is a lot of suspense and everything is in noir style. The screens and computers looks kind of like in *Blade Runner*. One of the actors look similar to [M. Emmet Walsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Emmet_Walsh) playing Harry Bryant, but it's not him, I've checked it.

As far as I can remember, there could be a scene with one of the crew members went outside (to die), and we see dust and sand streaming out from badly closed hatch. Also there was a scene where two crew members, one of them holding a gun, are sitting around and arguing about the storm.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on the SFF stack.

Answer (score 4):

Your initial description really reminds me of [Mission to Mars (2000)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0183523/).

There is a storm (obviously not natural) in it and the astronauts try to understand what it is. It's been a while since I've seen it so I can't recognize all the scenes you describe, but your description really stroke me as familiar.

This is a picture of a scene in the movie that shows the storm:

[image] [Source](http://johnkennethmuir.wordpress.com/category/brian-de-palma/page/2/)

Comment: Hmm, in some way it really matches well, while in others it doesn't. Worth a try at least.

Comment: @ChristianRau Indeed! Everything matches except some of the final descriptions the OP does (as far as I remember).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [Eye of the Storm](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0702730/) (Session 5 episode 17) From Sliders?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not. I could watch this episode.